# How to monitor Lists and Semaphores

Tags: hazelcast

Is there a way to monitor/view `list` data structures and `semaphores` in management center? The panel lists only some of the data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not supported in Hazelcast Management Center. Support for them is on our backlog but not assigned to a particular version yet.